# Unable to get HTML content from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape a web page with the requests library. However the element I want to scrape from the webpage goes missing after it is received locally . I tried changing headers and user agents but just cant figure it out.

I am allowed to use only python and its native libraries. Also, I am new to scraping.
Hope someone can help me out.

**Code :**

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'}

html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
```

Comment: There's nothing here anyone can use to help. Elements don't "go missing" after retrieving, the most *likely* explanation, without knowing anything else, is that the element isn't there on initial load and is being created dynamically.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the comment. Is it possible there are hidden elements? Also, is it true that we cannot scrape if the webpage gets the data from the front-end instead of a database request?

Comment: Hidden elements are still part of the DOM and would be included in the request. Elements added dynamically, *after the initial request is made*, would not be included in a single request, because they're not there until later. *Any* page can be scraped, but the process for scraping a dynamic page requires something that can run the JS on the page, like a headless browser.